Using EXISTS and Subquery in Snowflake
I have the following table in Snowflake
  categories VARIANT DEFAULT NULL,
  types VARIANT DEFAULT NULL,
  id VARCHAR(255)

categories = [{"name", "id"}]
types = [{"name", "id"}]

I want to select all the id's where they have type.name=x and category.name=y.
I tried to use subquery but its not working.
    SELECT 
      id
    FROM 
        TEST.TEST.TEST
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                VALUE:name::string
            FROM 
                TABLE(FLATTEN(input => categories)) 
            WHERE
                VALUE:name::string  = 'x'
        )
  AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                VALUE:name::string
            FROM 
                TABLE(FLATTEN(input => types)) 
            WHERE
                VALUE:name::string  = 'Y'
        )

I get the following error:
Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated


could you please provide sample data?

What does your actual data look like? Can you post some samples? [{"name", "id"}] doesn't look like a valid JSON

so if we make up some data that resembles what I think you are describing:
with data_cte as (
    select $1 as id, 
    parse_json($2) as categories, 
    parse_json($3) as types
    from values
    (1,'[{"name":"x","id":10},{"name":"a","id":20}]','[{"name":"w","id":11},{"name":"a","id":22}]'),
    (2,'[{"name":"y","id":12},{"name":"a","id":21}]','[{"name":"z","id":13},{"name":"a","id":23}]')
)

and then select using the first EXIST clause you have, albeit a little modifed:
SELECT 
    d.id,
    f.VALUE as f_val
FROM data_cte as d,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input => d.categories)) as f




ID
F_VAL




1
{"id": 10,"name": "x"}


1
{"id": 20,"name": "a"}


2
{"id": 12,"name": "y"}


2
{"id": 21,"name": "a"}



so if we now try your example we should get an error:
SELECT 
  id
FROM data_cte
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => categories)) 
    WHERE VALUE:name::string  = 'x'
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 2
    FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => types)) 
    WHERE VALUE:name::string  = 'Y'
)


Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

so if we change the data a bit more, use two CTE's to pre-build the list of values we are trying to do an EXIST over, then this form can be used.
with data_cte as (
    select $1 as id, 
    parse_json($2) as categories, 
    parse_json($3) as types
    from values
    (1,'[{"name":"x","id":10},{"name":"a","id":20}]','[{"name":"y","id":11},{"name":"a","id":22}]'),
    (2,'[{"name":"y","id":12},{"name":"x","id":21}]','[{"name":"z","id":13},{"name":"y","id":23}]')
), id_categories_x as (
    SELECT id
    FROM data_cte, 
        TABLE(FLATTEN(input => categories)) 
    WHERE VALUE:name::string  = 'x'
), id_types_y as (
    SELECT id
    FROM data_cte, 
        TABLE(FLATTEN(input => types)) 
    WHERE VALUE:name::string  = 'y'
)
SELECT 
  id
FROM data_cte as d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM id_categories_x as x
    WHERE x.id = d.id
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 2
    FROM id_types_y as y
    WHERE y.id = d.id
)


SELECT A.ID 
    ,B.VALUE:name::string
    ,C.VALUE:name::string
        
FROM 
    TEST.TEST.TEST  A, 
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input => categories)) B,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input => types)) C
WHERE
    B.VALUE:name::string  = 'x' AND  
    C.VALUE:name::string  = 'Y'



The EXISTS will early return or only trigger once, where-as this example if B or C has one hundered 'x''s this will give 100 rows, because this is a JOIN. This can be solved via a DISTINCT but that is more expensive.

Assuming your data resembles Simeon's test data, you could also look at overlapping sets
select id
from t, lateral flatten(input => categories)) 
where value:name::string  = 'x'
intersect
select id
from t, lateral flatten(input => type)) 
where value:name::string  = 'y'

